# remote: Not Found; Fatal: repository xxxx not found; NEW github

Tags: git, github, repository, remote-access

I made a new github account and tried pushing a new local project (git init) to the freshly made repository on github. I got the error about the remote not being found after running `git push -u origin main` . Most pages I have looked at say this error occurs when cloning a repository, but this is just the initial push. I have tried some of the following solutions:

- removing all git/github credentials in my windows credentials manager.
- adding the remote with my PAT, github username and repository name
- setting the remote url with my github username and repository name
- changing my global email to match the email associated with the new github acount
- And many various variations of above

I still get the fatal repository not found error. I know the repository exists:
https://github.com/cortex05/education-mk-3
I just cant push to it. Does anyone have any leads?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `set remote URL` before pushing, and if you are pushing to a private repo, you need to add your SSH keys to GitHub too.

To understand things, try to clone the repository you created. If it works, then your access rights are okay.

you can always place your code there: `git add`, `git commit` and `git push`